# Decompress, transform and compress back big file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, zlib

I have considerably big (30Gb gzipped, ~300Gb gunzipped) gzipped rdf file, which I need to process line by line and gzip back to another file. So here is what I currently have ([file](https://github.com/dgraph-io/benchmarks/blob/master/data/21million.rdf.gz) on test is ~150Mb gzipped)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const readline = require('readline');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('21million.rdf.gz').pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("21million.rdf");
const gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();

gzipStream.pipe(writeStream);


const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    output: gzipStream,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    gzipStream.write(`${line.toUpperCase()}\n`);
});

rl.on('close', () => {
    console.log('done');
    gzipStream.end();
});
```

The problem is with such flow I receive `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

So the question is - how can I set it up so I don't hit OOM issue?

PS. I'm aware it can be done with sed, awk, pert etc., yet I need to do it in js.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way Node.js handles [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). It is also known as [backpressuring](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/). This occurs when the Readable stream gives data quicker than the Writer can consume, which results into an increased memory usage since the data must be kept in memory until the entire process has completed.

One way to fix this issue is to use a [Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams) stream, which handles data transformation through the pipeline.

The following code should do what you're trying to achieve:

```js
const stream = require('stream');

const transformStream = new stream.Transform({
    writableObjectMode: true,
    transform: (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
        const chunkText = chunk.toString(encoding);
        const modifiedChunkText = chunkText.toUpperCase(); // apply modifications to the text
        callback(false, Buffer.from(modifiedChunkText, encoding));
    }
});

readStream // reads from 21million.rdf.gz
    .pipe(transformStream) // transforms data
    .pipe(gzipStream) // writes to output file
    .on('finish', () => {
        console.log('done');
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, this night work for uppercasing, but as I've mentioned, I need to process the file line by line, and I believe there are no guarantees that all lines in the chunk will be complete (first/last line won't be broken)